# Will const parameters and typecasting work as before under Delphi 64bit?

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, freepascal

As a general rule I have circumvented a lot of classical design traps when using pointers by taking advantage of Const (untyped) parameters rather than hard coded types. This gives me the benefit of speed when executing advanced graphical functions while leaving the technical details up to the compiler. It has also made it easy to use the same code in Delphi and Free Pascal with minimal changes.Lately however, I have begun to question this due to Embarcadero's vauge statements on the evolution of Delphi and it's upcomming safety model.

For instance, concider the following example:

```
Type TSomeDataProc = procedure (const aInput;var aOutput) of Object;

(* Convert 8-bit pixel to 16-bit pixel *)
Procedure TMyClass.ProcessSomeData08x565(Const aInput;var aOutput);
var r,g,b: Byte;
Begin
  FPalette.ExportTriplets(Byte(aInput),r,g,b);
  Word(aOutput):=(R SHR 3) SHL 11 or (G SHR 2) SHL 5 or (B SHR 3);
End;

(* Convert 16-bit pixel to 24-bit pixel *)
Procedure TMyClass.ProcessSomeData565x888(Const aInput;var aOutput);
Begin
  With TRGBTriple(aOutput) do
  Begin
   rgbtRed:=(((word(aInput) and $F800) shr 11) shl 3);
   rgbtGreen:= (((word(aInput) and $07E0) shr 5) shl 2);
   rgbtBlue:= ((word(aInput) and $001f) shl 3);
  end;
End;
```

We now have two procedures with identical declarations, but they handle the pixeldata very differently. This gives us the benefit of using a lookup table to get the correct "converter" method. This should be done in either the constructor or wherever the picture bitmap is allocated, like this:

```
Private
FLookup: Array[pf8bit..pf32bit,pf8bit..pf32bit] of TSomeDataProc;

Procedure TMyClass.Create;
Begin
  Inherited;
  FLookup[pf8bit,pf16bit]:=ProcessSomeData08x565;
  FLookup[pf16bit,pf24Bit]:=ProcessSomeData565x888;
end;
```

Whenever we need to convert pixels we simply look up the correct method and use it. The syntax remains the same for all the procedures - so we dont have to worry about "how" each procedure operates. As far as our class is concerned, they all look the same.

```
Procedure TMyClass.ConvertTo(aFormat:TpixelFormat);
Begin
 // Get function for the correct pixel converter
 FConvertProc:=FLookup[CurrentFormat,aFormat];

 //Use the pixel converter
 FConvertProc(GetSourcePixelAddr(x,y),GetTargetPixelAddr(x,y));
end;
```

The question is: **Will this kind of typecasting** (e.g: Const to Byte or any defined Record type) survive under 64bit? I personally cant see why not, but Embarcadero have been sort of vague regarding the new "safety" model and pointer-use, so I find it a bit hard to safeguard my code for the future.

Comment: I can't for the life of me see why you write it that way rather than: `ProcessSomeData(Const aInput: Byte; var aOutput: Word);`

Comment: You don't pass a pointer to that example code, do you? Out of curiosity, what's wrong with the built-in type system, what's pointer speed?

Comment: @Sertac Speed is the same here. There is a subtle difference between such a var typeless parameter and a const typeless parameter and a generic pointer: a const typeless parameter should not be modified, whereas a pointer can always be modified. And using such a typeless var can avoid typing some ^ characters in your code: PWord(aOutput)^ := 13 for instance. The generated assembler will be the same as word(aOutput) := 13.

Comment: @A.Bouchez - Interesting.. Thanks!

Comment: I'd **really** like to see how removing type-safety has allowed you to circumvent a run-time error. Please consider posting an example at Stack Overflow's [sister site for code reviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @David: The above proc was just a pseudo example. I have written graphics libraries where the input pixel-datatype can be 1,2,3 or 4 bytes long. Passing the entry adress as a const (or pointer) allows me to implement different methods for each pixelformat - but without hardcoding the datatype. Hence you get a uniform class interface that is easy to update and work with.

Comment: @A.Bounchez: Well one example would be casting pointers to Integers etc. (a lot of old graphics code out there use this). I tried to attack the problem by thinking differently: could I achieve more or less the same by avoiding typed pointers/Integer casting in my graphics code? While the blitter methods use pointers - the interface section to these methods are now "pascal clean", using const and var as much as possible.

Comment: You can use the same with a generic pointer type parameter, then typecasting this pointer to the good type, using procedure Test(aPointer: pointer); var aTypedType: PTypedType absolute aPointer; You can also use the "absolute" trick with var or const type parameters. I'm not sure which one is 'pascal cleaner' because you're loosing the strong type feature in both cases. Just a matter of taste and habit, IMHO... :)

Comment: @Jon OK, I see what you are doing. Personally I would use pointers for something like this. It feels more transparent to me and its just as (un)safe.

Comment: @A.Bouchez Of course, **absolute** may be disappearing from a future version of Delphi if Allen Bauer is to be believed.

Comment: @A.Bounches: Yes I know :) The pseudo code i posted here was just that.. pseudo. In a real life example the input parameter would be cast to a pointer (an PRGBTripletArray for instance). And this is the point of an "untypes" (i.e "unknown") data-source. For the 24bit implementation the aInput is expected to be TRGBTriple, but the 32 bit version of the same proc expected TRGBQuad. The 8bit version expectes a byte. So you have the same declaration, but it handles all the different formats.

Comment: @David I just heard about that... and also that his dream is to add a garbage collector to Delphi... I really don't understand his point... do those guys learn, and do they want another Delphi for DotNet experiment? We need non managed applications, with no garbage collection! The VCL ownership is some kind of garbage collection I like very much. Are they dreaming of reinventing the DotNet framework, since Anders Hejlsberg left Borland? Of course, I'm Mr Nobody, and you will certainly send me back to FPC in some years... :)

Comment: @A.Bouchez I think Allen intimated that changes will happen on new platforms (Mac, Linux) rather than on Windows. I think they are aware of the legacy. Any garbage collection will almost surely be optional.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: I did not say that i managed to escape any runtime errors, but rather make my code run more easily without hardcoding types, and thus avoiding conflicts that typically arise when porting code. Thats all. In my case between 32bit windows and 64bit mac using freepascal. When i hardcoded use of integer/pointer casts, it naturally crashed. But when i stopped doing this and made my code as "pascal" as possible, I avoided this.

Comment: Yes, you did say that. You said you "circumvented ... pointer errors." And just now, you said your code used to crash. Crashes are run-time errors. I don't know why you were using integer/pointer casts at all. Simple pointer/pointer casts should have sufficed.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: If you look at some of the graphics examples on torrys for raw-bitmap manipulation you will find plenty of Integer/pointer casts. So it's not so uncommon. You also removed the context in which i wrote - which in this case was "classical pointer errors". Perhaps "Classical design traps" would be better. English is not my native language. Also, converting code from 32bit to 64bit, i sort of expected there would be integer/pointer errors. Which is why I switched design model in the first place, to alter the way I work and avoid these flaws in the future.

Comment: @David IMHO there is no reason why the garbage collector will be only on Mac/Linux, since it will be a compiler feature (its implementation will need some magic at the compiler level), and the compiler is shared between all platforms (only the back-end/linker change). Another point: if the garbage collector is optional, why "absolute" keyword would be a problem? If you use an absolute var, you won't have a GC for it. Absolute is just a typecast between two pointers. If absolute is to be deprecated, also should be pointer typecasting. Just as in DotNet.

Comment: @A.Bouchez  Allen said that newer features like GC, those that are a big step from current Delphi will appear first on other platforms. I didn't express that well. He certainly didn't say only on those platforms. Better to try them out there first. You should listen to the podcast. As for absolute, I use it but would not miss it. There are other ways to achieve the same. What I would cry over would be loss of variant records!

Comment: @David Don't trust such long-term promises. We all know how it works. Listen to facts, not roadmaps, nor Chief-Scientist wishes. When the 64 bit compiler will be there, and cross-platform stable code generation... We could start about thinking about implementing a GC. About variant records, I couldn't agree more! If only variant records would stay, and have bit-level variants, to more easily match some C structures, I would be very pleased! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since such tricks are used in the RTL, I don't see deprecating a var or const typeless parameter without a lot of code breaking.

Embarcadero tries its best to maintain as much backward compatibility as possible.

They even should include back the inline asm in the 64 bit compiler, after having first made some notification about the use of an external assembler.

And such a modification won't have anything to do with the 64 bit model, whereas the x86-64 assembler was a new piece of code to write.

So you should post this question of the official Embarcadero newsgroup, but I think you don't have to worry about this.

Comment: Allen Bauer already reported in a recent podcast at http://www.delphi.org that inlined assembly would be supported (with some limitations) in the Delphi 64-bit compiler.

Comment: @Remy Yes, this is what I said. A good back move. There was some kind of panic in the newsgroups when they told about getting rid of the inline assembler in the Delphi 64 bit compiler. The new "Starter" edition is also something good. But when I heard Allen speaking about the future of Delphi, and a garbage collector, I start to panic again. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Note that FPC already did change the CONST parameter, though not in this case.

For the normal case, CONST is not guaranteed by reference anymore for all calling conventions, but follows whatever the respective ABI specifies. A new parameter type, CONSTREF is guaranteed to be by reference.

Like all breakage of compatibility it is the problem that in TP/Delphi CONST is always by ref, but TP/Delphi is also always x86.

Among others all STDCALL functions change, like e.g. IUnknown.Queryinterface:

http://wiki.freepascal.org/User_Changes_Trunk#IInterface.QueryInterface.2C_._AddRef_and_._Release_definitions_have_been_changed

The reason is more or less that in these cases, x86 ABI information entered the generic interface, something which is not cross-architecture compatible. So one has to guess if it is part of the language, or part of the x86 implementation of the language.

Note that IUnknown is also used on other platforms for e.g. Firefox' XPCOM

Delphi might also hit such snags, but I think they primarily will effect functions/methods with explicit calling convention requirements, because one can change the internal convention to suit needs, but one can't practically change the rest of the world ((XP)COM or existing C(++) libraries) to suit existing code in Delphi